# Adding element to JList does not work

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to add a new element to my empty JList but it doesn't appear. I'm running it on the EDT (I've very low information on that subject)

```
public void populateProjectsList(List<Project> projectsList2) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DefaultListModel<String> listModel = (DefaultListModel) projectsList.getModel();
            listModel.clear();
            for (Project project : projectsList2) {
                System.out.println(project.id + ") " + project.name);
                listModel.addElement(project.id + ") " + project.name);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

System.out.println works, I see the correct output that I wish to be added but the list is still empty as it is. I tried listModel.addElement in an action listener and it worked.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: The app uses SQLite to retrieve the projects list, then it creates a Project object for each project and stores them in a List. That's why it was not easy to provide a runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for instance when called from ListSelectionListener, see below.

My guess is that you add the items correctly to JList, but they are not seen, because the JList has so small dimensions, that its content cannot be seen. Work on the layout of the components in your window, or put some data into JList at the time you add it to the window. It may well be some other reason, of course.

A working example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main()
    {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Hello");

        DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        model.addElement("hello");
        model.addElement("hi");
        model.addElement("ola");

        projectsList = new JList<>(model);
        fr.add(projectsList);
        fr.pack();
        fr.setVisible(true);

        projectsList.addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) 
                    {
                        List<Project> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();
                        toAdd.add(new Project(7, "seven"));
                        toAdd.add(new Project(10, "ten"));
                        toAdd.add(new Project(4, "four"));
                        populateProjectsList(toAdd);
                        projectsList.removeListSelectionListener(this);                
                    }
                }
        );      
    }

    JList projectsList;

    private void populateProjectsList(List<Project> projectsList2) 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = (DefaultListModel<String>) projectsList.getModel();
                    listModel.clear();
                    for (Project project : projectsList2) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(project.id + ") " + project.name);
                        listModel.addElement(project.id + ") " + project.name);
                    }                    
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private class Project 
    {
        int id;
        String name;

        public Project(int id, String name) 
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious as why you would ever want to add new items to a `JLIst` when you change the selected item...

Comment: The JList has reasonable dimensions, and as I stated I tried using the same code through an action listener and it worked. I'm guessing the problem is something to do with threading and EDT, but I can't figure out the problem.